# Layout items adjustment issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design layout like below but I am unable to design. I don't know how set layout without dp. How can I do without assigning **dp to height & weight**?

Items should be centered with same size of all card views and is it possible to not assign dp to image view height width but all images should be of same size.

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/NewsImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NewsTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".166"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="News"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/primarytext"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NewsDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="No News Feed"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/News_Channel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".166"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/News_Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".166"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I want this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have opened `<RelativeLayout>` but didn't closed it. Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_news"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/NewsImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NewsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".166"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="News"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/primarytext"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/NewsDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="No News Feed"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/News_Channel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".166"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/News_Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".166"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will give constant height to card view it will not vary, and you can get your desired layout.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
```

Comment: what if I open this in tab with constant value ?

Comment: open this in tab means you are saying adding it dynamically ??

Comment: I want responsiveness in this layout, it's easy to give constant values.